# Problems with JavaScript progress bar loading infinitely

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I call this progress bar function when the page loads and with every eventListener in order to give users feedback when they interact with various inputs.

Problem: tt seems like the function is running "forever" when I console log (progressBar.style.width)

Here's my code:

HTML

```
   <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria- 
       valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
   </div>
```

CSS + bootstrap

```
.bar_container{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Function to load the bar

```
progressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar")

   function loadBar() {
    let fill = 0
    window.setInterval(function() {

        fill += 60

        if (fill === 100) {
            clearInterval()
        } else {
            progressBar.style.width = fill + "%"
            console.log(progressBar.style.width) // seems like this function runs infinitely ???
        }

    }, 50)
}
```

Call function with event listener

```
document.querySelector('#show-pm').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    filters.hideAm = e.target.checked
    filterMeetings(filters)
    progressBar.style.width = "0%" //Intending to reset the progress to 0% ???
    loadBar()
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is #show-pm

Comment: That's a checkbox input that also calls a function that filters an array of objects by am/pm. The filtering happens so fast that user have reported they didn't notice it did anything, which is why I want to have a progress bar give them feedback.

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that u up fill 60 so fill never will be 100 so and never interval finish

if your fill up 1  then change it  to

```
 function loadBar() {
    let fill = 0
    window.setInterval(function() {

        fill ++

        if (fill === 100) {
            clearInterval()
        } else {
            progressBar.style.width = fill + "%"
            console.log(progressBar.style.width) // seems like this function runs infinitely ???
        }

    }, 50)
}
```

if it will up as 60 then u need to say

```
function loadBar() {
    let fill = 0
    window.setInterval(function() {

        fill +=60

        if (fill >= 100) {
            clearInterval()
        } else {
            progressBar.style.width = fill + "%"
            console.log(progressBar.style.width) // seems like this function runs infinitely ???
        }

    }, 50)
}
```

Comment: If u didn't solve  fast initialize the sidebar then u can check this example also https://jsfiddle.net/ohfq0nwb/